# Need to modify PZEM-004T 10A to 100A

Tags: current-measurement

I accidentally purchased PZEM-004T 10A instead of 100A version. I have spare CT transformer from 100A version. It is possible somehow to modify 10A version to be able to measure 100A? I can solder whatever is needed, but not sure what and if modification is possible.

See page 6 and 7 in [datasheet](https://innovatorsguru.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/PZEM-004T-V3.0-Datasheet-User-Manual.pdf)

Comment: Please add a link to a datasheet or website of the supplier of the device. Otherwise everyone who would want to help you has to do that work over and over again.

Comment: Added datasheet